# Show some specefic number on gauge highcharts axis labels

Tags: highcharts

I want to show some number on gauge data label like this:
[image: gauge with user select number]

I try to use `category` and `formatter` option in  **`yAxis`** like this but faild!

```
categories: ['0','3','7','14'],
```

and

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        if(this.value == '0' ||this.value == '3' ||this.value == '7' ||this.value == '14') 
            return this.value;
    }
},
```

What is wrong with this method? also any other solution will be appreciated .
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5zYf/) i am going to work on.

Comment: Please check the below fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-dual/

Comment: @APaul Those numbers are automatically generated. but i want some specific numbers to show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i solved this. here is what i add to `yAxis` :

```
  rotation:'auto',      
  labels: {
      distance: 20,
      formatter: function() {
          if(this.value == '0' ||this.value == '3' ||this.value == '7' ||this.value == '14') 
              return this.value;
      }
  },
  tickInterval: 1,
  minorTickLength:0,
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5zYf/4/)

Comment: Intersting that you had to specify the minorTickLength. Good spot.

Comment: @SteveP YaH :) i had to read documentation and yes that was there however it didn't mention it or any fiddle about that.